# how to give Azure Service Principal the same rights as my own user?

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm researching Azure and wanted to use a Service Principal when logging in through Azure CLI instead of authenticating through the web login method. I created a Service Principal with `az ad sp create-for-rbac` with the scope on the root of my subscription and role 'Owner'. I can succesfully login using the Service Principal but when I try to do `az ad sp list`, I get the error that I don't have enough privileges:
`azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

When I look at the Access control (IAM) tab in my subscription blade in the portal, I can see the Service Principal is Owner, and my own account is both Owner and Service administrator.

Is there a way to give the Service Principal exactly the same rights as my own account has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently giving an SP the 'Owner' role is not enough. You have the give it the 'Directory Readers' role. This is not possible using the Azure CLI or Portal though. You have to use the Azure AD Graph API, easiest way to do this is using https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/.

Second caveat is, you can't use the graphexplorer site using your own Azure account (in my case I had a simple personal Azure setup with only myself as admin), but you have to create a user in your Azure AD. I gave it the Global Administrator role just to be sure, I'm not certain what the minimum role would be to be able to use the Graph API.

Now, the steps to add give the SP the Directory Readers role are a bit long to explain here, I found them here: https://lnx.azurewebsites.net/directory-roles-for-azure-ad-service-principal/

Not sure why this needs to be so convoluted and why this is not to be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If your sp has `Owner` role, the command `az ad sp list` could list your sps.

I suggest you could close your current shell and  re-open a new shell, using following command to login your subscription.

```
az login --service-principal -u <client id> -p <client secret> --tenant <tenant id>
```

Comment: If possible, I suggest you could test it on Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: on cloud shell az login is disabled cause it automatically authenticates. I already login the way you propose, but still, it seems I have hardly any rights.

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts Sorry for the later reply. Do you check your sp role on Azure Portal? Like this https://imgur.com/a/ohm4d

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts Also, what is your Azure CLi version? `az -v`. The latest version is 2.0.23. If you don't use the latest version, I suggest you could update it. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. See this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#update-the-cli).

Comment: np, and happy new year! I was already using az cli 2.0.23. The IAM tab in my subscription shows the sp as Owner, I had also tried giving it the Security Admin and User Access Administrator role, but that didn't help either. It seems I can do about anything with the sp, except for sp related stuff. I can't create another sp with my sp for example, which makes it hard to setup an AKS cluster in an automated way.

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts It is very strange. I am sure if your sp has owner role. you could create aks cluster. If possible, could you create a new sp? Another question the account your login Azure Portal has owner role? The account has permission to create a sp?

Comment: Your user which use login Portal has `Global Administrator` permission? Like this https://imgur.com/a/9Gb32 ?

Comment: I already recreated the sp a couple of times :) First with az ad sp create, later with az ad sp create-for-rbac. My own portal user is global admin yes, like in the image. When I try to create an sp, using the first sp, I get the following error: https://imgur.com/a/Hi94Y In AAD I have the option 'Users can register applications' enabled (already was by default).

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts It is like a permission issue. Could you share your steps to create this sp.

Comment: @NicolasMommaerts I suggest you could create this sp on Azure Portal and give it Owner role. See this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: I created a new sp on the Azure Portal according to the link you gave me, exactly the same problem when doing az ad sp list...

Comment: I solved it, will add the solution as an answer. You were right, it were permissions missing (obviously), but it is not so easy to add them.